# Cannot move function into another file?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am having some trouble with moving a function into a separate file when using the rocket library.

I am able to compile and run the [getting-started-example](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/getting-started/) from rockets web page, like this:

```
// main.rs
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

#[get("/")]
pub fn index() -> &'static str { "Hello, world!" }

fn main() { rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![index]).launch(); }
```

But if I move the `index()` function into its own file, in the same directory, like this:

```
// main.rs
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

mod index;

fn main() { rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![index]).launch(); }
```

```
// index.rs 
#[get("/")]
pub fn index() -> &'static str { "Hello, world!" }
```

I am then presented with the error message:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `static_rocket_route_info_for_index` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:41
  |
8 |     rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![index]).launch();
  |                                         ^^^^^ not found in this scope
  |
help: consider importing this static
  |
5 | use crate::index::static_rocket_route_info_for_index;
  |
```

What does this mean in this context and how do i fix it?

Comment: There's a confusion between the `index` function and the `index` module. You should either `use index::index;` or write `routes![index::index]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jmb commented, the problem was that the file `index` and the function `index` got mixed up.
So the solution was to specify the function as `index::index`.